# Adding moment third-party library to Angular CLI application

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-cli

I am trying to add moment to my angular 2 CLI app.

I followed the instructions here: [Official Angular CLI instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-momentjs-library-to-your-project).

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bignibou-client-new",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.22",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.2.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my angular-cli-build.js:

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'ng2-bootstrap/**/*',
      'ng2-translate/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'angular2-moment/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'moment/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

and my system-config.ts:

```
// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment':{
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
  'ng2-bootstrap',
  'ng2-translate',
  'angular2-moment',
  'moment',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
    'ng2-translate': 'vendor/ng2-translate',
    'angular2-moment': 'vendor/angular2-moment',
    'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

Here is the error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ember-cli-live-reload.js 404 ()
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM197:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js as "moment" from http://localhost:8080/app/main.component.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/locale/fr.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM197:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-bootstrap/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM197:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-bootstrap/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM197:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment.js/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM197:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**:

Here is how I import moment and moment locale:

```
import "moment/locale/fr";
import * as moment from "moment";
```

**edit 2**: If change the moment dependency to `'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment'`, I still get the following error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ember-cli-live-reload.js 
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM327:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js as "moment/locale/fr" from http://localhost:8080/app/main.component.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM327:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-bootstrap/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM327:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-bootstrap/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM327:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/index.js 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM327:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

**edit 3**: removing the third party dependencies from the barrel section gives me another error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate as "ng2-translate/ng2-translate" from http://localhost:8080/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463
http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
http://localhost:8080/vendor/moment/moment/locale/fr.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
12system.src.js:371 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:371
http://localhost:8080/vendor/ng2-bootstrap Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular2-moment Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
system.src.js:371 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:371
```

**edit 4**: Using this system-config:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment':'vendor/moment'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment':{
    format: 'cjs',
    main:'moment.js'
  }
};
```

now gives me this error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ember-cli-live-reload.js 
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM371:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate as "ng2-translate/ng2-translate" from http://localhost:8080/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404) loading http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/ng2-translate/ng2-translate 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM371:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
12system.src.js:371 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:371ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/ng2-bootstrap 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM371:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
2system.src.js:371 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:371ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/angular2-moment 404 ()scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM371:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
system.src.js:371 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:371ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

**edit 5**: Here is my final config and it seems to be sorting the issue

```
// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment':'vendor/moment'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment':{
    format: 'cjs',
    main:'moment.js'
  },
  'ng2-bootstrap':{
    format: 'cjs',
    main:'ng2-bootstrap.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
   'ng2-bootstrap',
   'ng2-translate',
   'angular2-moment',
   'moment',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
    'ng2-translate': 'vendor/ng2-translate',
    'angular2-moment': 'vendor/angular2-moment',
    'moment': 'vendor/moment',
     'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

Comment: I'd guess that the error is where you are importing from moment, could you include that code snippet in the question?

Comment: @JarodMoser: I doubt it has anything to do with the way I import moment because as you can see the issue occurs with other 3rd-party dependencies...

Comment: One difference that I do see is that my third party maps in the system-config.ts are in the map at the top of the file, just below the User Configuration, rather than in the System.config map at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I really doubt the order of elements in the files matter...

Comment: How about removing the third party libraries from the barrels section... the Official Angular CLI instructions that you linked to don't say anything about adjusting what the barrels are

Comment: I have tried that to no avail either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment npm module has no `index.js` file.

that's why the error:

`/vendor/moment/moment/index.js`.

This is the only code that goes into `system-config.ts`:

```
 /****************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 *****************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */

const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {

  'moment': {
    format: 'cjs',
    main: 'moment.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

after you put:

`'moment/**/*.+(js|js.map)'`

in your `angular-cli-build.js` you need to kill the server and run `ng buid`.

testing:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import "moment/locale/fr";
import * as moment from "moment";
// let now = moment().format('LLLL');

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<button (click)="testing()" >click me</button>',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';


// public now = moment();


testing(){


console.log(moment.locale()); //  gives fr

}

}
```

Comment: I changed to `'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment'` I still get the error as mentioned in my edit 2...

Comment: Yes, it failed, as soon as I put a moment script into the class. Try to use the user configuration. no need to change anything below: `* Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.`

Comment: I have edited my post to take into account your comment.

Comment: JS_astronauts: we are onto something. The custom `packages const` you provided seems to make a big difference. However, one stills needs to modify the part below the line `* Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI `

Comment: I am marking this answer as accepted. Please note though that one does need to modify the barrels section as well as the map in System.config.

Comment: @balteo What modifications did you make? Could you please share them? I am having similar problems with moment and lodash with CLI. After following the CLI-docs, itt still does not work. I see both moment and lodash in my vendor directory after build, but the libraries cannot be found when the application starts.

Comment: Have a look at my **edit 5**. If you still can't make it, please open a question and link it here.